# Method to convolve a 4D array with a 2D array (different kernel for each element)?

Tags: arrays, numpy, image-processing, scipy, signal-processing

I would like to do a convolution using a different kernel for each element. My signal array has the shape `n x m` and the kernels have the shape `[i, i]`. I have the kernels in a 4D array of shape `n x m x i x i`, such that the value at `[x, y]` is the `i x i` kernel to apply to the element at `[x, y]` in the signal array. For example:

```
2D signal array:
[[0 1]
 [5 9]]

4D kernel array, having a different 3x3 kernel for each signal array element:
[[[[1 0 1]  | [[0 0 0]
   [0 1 0]  |  [0 0 0]
   [1 0 1]] |  [0 0 0]]
   ------------------------
  [[1 1 1]  | [[0 1 0]
   [1 1 1]  |  [1 0 1]
   [1 1 1]] |  [0 1 0]]]]

Desired "convolution" process:
[[1 0 1]    [[- - -]         [[0 0 0]    [[- - -]
 [0 1 0]  •  [- 0 1]  = 9     [0 0 0]  •  [0 1 -]  = 0
 [1 0 1]]    [- 5 9]]         [0 0 0]]    [5 9 -]]
  
[[1 1 1]    [[- 0 1]          [[0 1 0]    [[0 1 -]
 [1 1 1]  •  [- 5 9]  = 15     [1 0 1]  •  [5 9 -] = 6
 [1 1 1]]    [- - -]]          [0 1 0]]    [- - -]]

Desired result:
[[9 0]
 [15 6]]
```

I can do this by looping over each convolution window, but that's slow for large arrays:

```py
def fancy_convolve(signal, kernels):
   kernel_size = kernels[0][0][0].shape[0]
   pad_width = int(kernel_size / 2)
   padded_signal = numpy.pad(signal, pad_width, 'constant',
                             constant_values=0)
   output = numpy.empty(signal.shape)
   for x in range(signal.shape[0]):
      for y in range(signal.shape[1]):
         signal_window = padded_signal[x:x+kernel_size, y:y+kernel_size]
         kernel = kernels[x, y]
         output[x, y] = numpy.dot(
            signal_window.flatten(), kernel.flatten())
   return output
```

Is there a function to do this efficiently in numpy, scipy, or another library? Is convolution the right word for it? I've looked at `scipy.ndimage.convolve` and `scipy.signal.convolve`, which allow higher dimensions but still only one kernel, and `numpy.tensordot`, which doesn't do the sliding window part of convolution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To make it straightforward without additional consideration about the layout of the arrays. I would combine a stride trick and an Einsteing sum.

```py
def efficient_fancy_convolve(signal, kernels):
    kernel_size = kernels[0][0][0].shape[0]
    pad_width = int(kernel_size / 2)
    padded_signal = numpy.pad(signal, pad_width, 'constant',
                             constant_values=0)
    p1 = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
           padded_signal, kernels.shape, 2*padded_signal.strides)
    return np.einsum('xyjk,xyjk->xy', p1, kernels)
```

Then a quick test

```py
x = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)
kernels = np.random.randn(1000, 1000, 10, 10)

x1 = fancy_convolve(x, kernels) # 3.7s
x2 = efficient_fancy_convolve(x, kernels) # 139ms
assert np.allclose(x1, x2)
```